# Facebook Retrive Data using Graph API using c#

Tags: c#, .net, facebook

i have created desktop Facebook application using c# .net. i want to retrieve users message,post and chat history. which is convenient way to retrieve users all information.i have started with Facebook Graph API but i am not getting any example.

can any one help me ?

Comment: You can not get all information at once. Call the API individually to get data you require.

Comment: yah i will call API as per requirement but can u give me any link from where i find examples or toolkit for same. and thanks for replay

Comment: @Chandu-Indyaah : how can I call an API to get number of likes on my post

Answer (score 8):

A bit late to the party but anyway:

Add a reference to System.Net.Http and Newtonsoft.Json

```
string userToken = "theusertokentogiveyoumagicalpowers";

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com");

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync($"me?fields=name,email&access_token={userToken}").Result;

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    var jsonRes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result);

    var email = jsonRes["email"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to developer.facebook.com -> Tools & Support -> Select Graph API Explorer

Here U get FQL Query, Access Token

Then write code in C#.....

```
var client = new FacebookClient();
client.AccessToken = Your Access Token;

//show user's profile picture
dynamic me = client.Get("me?fields=picture");
pictureBoxProfile.Load(me.picture.data.url);

//show user's birthday
me = client.Get("me/?fields=birthday");
labelBirthday.Text = Convert.ToString(me.birthday);
```

Comment: FacebookClient() is that from a reference you have added?

Comment: I found 'a' FacebookClient class in this project: https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk in nuget it's simply called 'Facebook' by Outercurve Foundation. Haven't tested it yet, but about to.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/380635/Csharp-Application-Integration-with-Facebook-Twitt

I hope this will help you.!!!

Comment: Thanks for replay but i want to retrieve information from Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the Graph explorer tool on Developer.facebook.com , go to Tools and select graph explorer, its a nice tool which gives you exact idea about what you can fetch by sending "GET" and "POST" method on FB Graph APis

Answer (score 0):

From what i see the app now only uses webhooks to post data to a data endpoint (in your app) at which point you can parse and use this. (FQL is deprecated). This is used for things like messaging.

A get request can be send to the API to get info - like the amt. of likes on your page.

The docs of FB explain the string you have to send pretty nicely. Sending requests can be done with the webclient, or your own webrequests. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bay1b5dh(v=vs.110).aspx

Then once you have a string of the JSON formatted page you can parse this using JSON.NET library. It's available as a NUGEt package.